# using image in a cell in AG-Grid PLAIN JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Here's my code:

```js
var tableData = [];
for (var i in data){
    tableData.push({title: data[i]['title'], sku: data[i]['sku'], size: data[i]['size'], image: data[i]['image'], uuid: data[i]['uuid']})
}

const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [{field: "title"},{field: "sku"},{field: "size"},{field: "image"},{field: "uuid"}],
    rowData: tableData
}

const container = document.getElementById('tableShow')
new agGrid.Grid(container, gridOptions)
```

For the "image" field... The current string is a URL to an image, I would like to embed the image into each cell in the table.

I've found examples but they're in Vue or something else and i'm having trouble trying to make it work in plain JS.

Comment: can you just code the `<img src='${data[i]['image']}' />` into the tableData.push ?

Comment: @Kinglish no, it just ends up being the HTML string in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can render images in a cell by using a [Custom Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/component-cell-renderer/#top).

See the following example in the documentation which showcases how you can achieve this: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/component-cell-renderer/#example-cell-renderer